# Conditional formatting for entire row based on fixed column

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

How do I create the following conditonal formatting:

```
If the date in G3 is older than today, turn all of row 3 red
```

So in other words I want my entire row to be formatted based on the value in the relevant Date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole table or range, add a new rule and select Use a formula... Then input this as the formula:

`=$G3<TODAY()`

**For more info, if you or anyone else doesn't know:**

Using the $ fixes the cell reference. $G3 would allow you move the row reference but would fix the column reference, G$3 would do the opposite and $G$3 fixes it completely.

By setting the reference as $G3, you can drag the formatting down and it will work for each row, but if you drag it accross it will always look at your date column.

You can quickly change the cell reference fixing by selecting the cell reference within your formula and hitting F4.

TODAY ends in () because it is a formula with no parameters.

**A final note**

If you haven't already, I would recommend adding another conditional format that formats the row orange if `=$G3=TODAY()`, so that users can easily identify rows about to turn red.